# SetMaxVideoDecodeResolution example on Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I tried to Change the Video Resolution and I found one property. But I don't know how it works in Roku. Pls, Provide Syntax or How to use this property on ROKU.

Answer (score 1):

This function is used to lowering down the supported resolution of your device. For example, if your device supports 1080p resolution, you can lowerdown it to 720p using this function. Generally, when a channel runs on roku device, roku os assigns a fix memory for the graphics of that channel (called texture memory). Video playback of the channel also uses this memory. If that texture memory is insufficient for any channel it can be handled either optimizing the channel or lowering down the maximum supported resolution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can Change Video screen using this function?

Comment: Using this function you can change only your device max supported resolution. You can not fix video screen resolution using this.

Comment: Ok i satisfied with your answer

Comment: Hi @NikunjChaklasiya. Sorry, unable to understand your requirements. Can you post it as separate question with some code snapshot please. I will try to understand then.